# Trimm the text from a content inside a expander

Tags: xaml

I am working on a xaml view which has a custom expandable element, that inherites from `System.Windows.Controls.Expander`. Inside this expander there is a content, which is a `contentControl.Content` element, along with a header and some extra security elements that are not relevant now.

This view is designed for a small screen and therefore does not have a horizontal scroll bar. The preferred behaviour is to break the text inside the content, even if that means to add a vertical scroll. The content is defined like this:

`Content="{Binding Model.DebugText}`

Question is: how can I implement such thing?

I have checked the MSDN documentation but I don't seem to find anything related to modify the behaviour of the content:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx 
http://10.112.241.50/DevDocu/Online/topic39042.html

Comment: If it's only Text you'll be entering as Content, you can replace the ContentPresenter in the control Template with a TextBlock bound to `{TemplateBinding Content}` and set `TextWrapping` directly on it. Or you could just put a `TextBlock` as the Content since Content should support any CLR object and do the same.

Comment: I'm affraid I am **very** new to xaml and I haven't understand what you have said. Isn't there a simpler way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, we've all been there. So as example.

```
<Expander>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.DebugText}" WordWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Expander>
```

Then you're just passing in a TextBlock as Content. Or if you wanted to get fancy, turn it into a ReadOnly TextBox so users can copy/paste the DebugText out of it also.